# SQL Query : Optimize way to find if the latest execution Id (max) is a Failure status record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a SQL table which stores the job sync status of Students profile. An entry is inserted by a background job for each student based on the job execution status. For example-- for any attribute change for a student, a record will be inserted into this table. As of now, this table has become huge overtime in size and has around 70M records.

The table schema look like below

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProfileSync](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Success] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [EntityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProfileSync] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
      [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProfileSync_StudentNumber] ON [dbo].[ProfileSync]
(
    [StudentNumber] ASC,
    [EntityId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`Success` column indicates three values 1, 0, -1 where 1 represents the success status, 0 in progress and -1 failure. `EntityId` is a int column which stores business data.

There is a reporting tool which fetches the data from this table and displays the status of last failed student sync profile. The **query** is written like

```
SELECT 
    PS.EntityId, PS.StudentNumber
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        StudentNumber, 
        MAX(Id) Id
    FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync] 
    GROUP BY StudentNumber
) AS A INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProfileSync] PS ON A.Id = PS.Id AND Success = -1
```

The above query takes long time to execute (around 20 secs on my local machine) which seems to be correct as it is scanning all the rows of the table. Is there anyother way to write an **optimize** query so that it does not scan the full table to fetch the required?

I've also tried using CTE, but it does not give better result (worse result)

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
   SELECTs
        StudentNumber, Id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By StudentNumber ORDER BY Id desc) AS RowNum
        FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync] 
)
SELECT PS.SyncStatusId, PS.StudentNumber
FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync] PS
INNER Join Results_CTE R ON R.Id = PS.Id
WHERE R.RowNum = 1 AND PS.Success = -1
```

Please suggest the optimize way to write the query?

Note - I've changed the name of actual business entities to represent as Student table/object. In actual enterprise application, the business entities/table have completely different name. As there would be suggestions related to archiving the records from this table or other design change so please don't deviate from query related to it's optimization.

Comment: Why do you need join in second query? Just select rows where `rownum = 1` and filter by `success` column in the CTE

Comment: RowNum filter can not be put in CTE directly.

Comment: I was suggesting to transfer condition `Success = -1` inside the CTE. And filter by `rownum = 1` outside the CTE, but without any join

Comment: Then the query will not return the latest failure, it fetches based on the last failed record for a student (even after there was a job which was successful). I believe you want to change the query like this : `;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
   SELECT
  StudentNumber, Id, SyncStatusId,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By StudentNumber ORDER BY Id desc) AS RowNum
  FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync]
  WHERE Success = -1
)
SELECT StudentNumber, Id, SyncStatusId
FROM Results_CTE R
WHERE R.RowNum = 1`

Comment: I thought you were looking for last failed record for a student. But if you are looking for a row which is latest and is failed for a student, then transfer condition `Success = -1` outside th CTE. `;WITH Results_CTE AS ( SELECT StudentNumber, Id, SyncStatusId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By StudentNumber ORDER BY Id desc) AS RowNum FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync]) SELECT StudentNumber, Id, SyncStatusId FROM Results_CTE R WHERE R.RowNum = 1 and Success = -1`

Comment: Thanks Uzi, but i've already tried the one you have mentioned, even the performance of mentioned query is worse than group by query (the first query in my question).  I've executed the query with Execution Plan enabled and observed that most of the time taken by query is in Sorting step as it is working on full table set.

Comment: Try to create covering indexes for both queries and compare performance. Or another option will be to create indexed view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reduce the records for aggregation operation by filtering them at earliest.
Try something like this-

```
    SELECT PS.SyncStatusId, PS.StudentNumber
FROM 
(
        Select StudentNumber, MAX(ID) id from [dbo].[ProfileSync]
        WHERE  StudentNumber IN (
        SELECT
            StudentNumber
        FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync] 
        WHERE Success = -1
        )
        GROUP BY StudentNumber
        ) AS A INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProfileSync] PS ON A.Id = PS.Id and Success = -1
```

Comment: Thanks. It does the trick :).  The query returns a result in 1 sec (compare to min which was ~20 secs). However, in a situation (worst case) when atleast a failure record exist for a student then query will perform in same time as `GroupBy` clause query mentioned in my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got this wrong completely... Try this modified query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
       PS.SyncStatusId
      ,PS.StudentNumber 
FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync] PS 
WHERE PS.Success=-1
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PS.StudentNumber ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC)
```

The combination of `TOP 1 WITH TIES` together with an `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY xyz ORDER BY abc)` returns all rows wich get a `row_number` of `1`.

An index on `Success` will help to reduce this quickly and an index on `LastModifiedDate` would support the sorting.

Comment: Are you referring query like this `SELECT 
  PS.SyncStatusId, PS.StudentNumber
FROM [dbo].[ProfileSync] PS
WHERE PS.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 x.Id
             FROM ProfileSync AS x 
             WHERE x.StudentNumber = PS.StudentNumber 
               AND x.Success = -1 
             ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC)`? 1. It's does not return the required output 2. It's slow compare to exiting groupBy query.

Comment: @user1672994 I've got this wrong... Try the modified query. If this does not help, please read about [Creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, will check the MCVE. however, the query still returning additional records. On my dataset, the `GroupBy` query returns only 14 records, but this modified query returns 1008 records.

Comment: @user1672994 Sorry, one mistake: Add `DESC` to `LastModifiedDate`...  The `ROW_NUMBER` should return exactly one row per `StudentNumber` which is the latest according to `LastModifiedDate` and therefore get's the number `1`. All `1s` are filter by `TOP 1 with TIES`. If this date is not unique per StudentNumber this might return additional rows, but I don't think so. Did you place the filter for `Success=-1`? This should be rather fast (with indexes!) as it will filter failed rows only and do the rest against this smaller set.

Comment: I'm trying to find the latest record to return per student if it is marked as failure. The query you have mentioned will fetch the last failed record (even there would be successful sync record (after failure), the query will give one record for a student).

Comment: @user1672994 Okay, I see. You can add `AND PS.LastModifiedDate>(SELECT MAX(x.LastModifiedDate) FROM dbo.ProfileSync AS x WHERE x.StudentNumber=PS.StudentNumber AND x.Success<>-1)` to the `WHERE`. Don't forget the indexes...